# How to quickly reorder posts in the admin panel that will persist for the wp-api

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, order, wp-api

I generally use the [Intuitive Custom Post Order](https://wordpress.org/plugins/intuitive-custom-post-order) plugin for any WordPress sites I work with so clients can order their posts visually.

For this project, I'm using WordPress as an admin panel and consuming it's data with an Ember.js front-end.

(using wp-api V.2) The re-ordered order doesn't show in the JSON and I'm guessing the plugin stores the new order in an in-between piece of PHP.

Besides manually changing the date of each post, what are my options to allow my client an intuitive way to re-order posts in a way that persists?

Comment: what version of wp-api you use ??

Comment: @Ahed Eid - Version 2

Comment: If it stores the new order into `menu_order` then one can order *hierarchical* post types with e.g. `?orderby=menu_order&order=asc`

Comment: Your option is to write code that does it, or modify the plugin

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume it stores the custom order into the `menu_order` column in the `wp_posts` table.

If you mean the hierarchical `page` post type (supports *page-attributes*) then one can order with the query variables:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/?orderby=menu_order&order=asc
```

If you mean the `post` post type with:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/
```

there's a way using the `rest_{post_type}_query` filter:

```
/**
 * Set orderby to 'menu_order' for the 'post' post type
 */
add_filter( "rest_post_query", function( $args, $request )
{
    $args['orderby'] = 'menu_order';
    return $args;
}, 10, 2 );
```

We might want to restrict this further. Skimming through the `WP_REST_Request` class we can see there's a handy `get_param()` public method that we could make use of:

```
/**
 * Support for 'wpse_custom_order=menu_order' for the 'post' post type
 */
add_filter( "rest_post_query", function( $args, $request )
{
    if( 'menu_order' === $request->get_param( 'wpse_custom_order' ) )
        $args['orderby'] = 'menu_order';

    return $args;
}, 10, 2 );
```

where we activate it through a custom `wpse_custom_order` parameter:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?wpse_custom_order=menu_order&order=asc
```

There's also the dynamically generated `rest_query_var-orderby` filter.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Although do note that `/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/?orderby=menu_order&order=asc` won't work by default. I'm adding a filter using `rest_<custom_post_type>_query`

Answer (score 0):

Ordering posts with menu_order as orderby parameter will give invalid parameter error e.g.

`http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?orderby=menu_order&order=asc`

`Invalid parameter(s): orderby (orderby is not one of date, id, include, title, slug)`

At this time there's no filter to add another orderby option
https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/blob/2.0-beta13/lib/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php#L1666

you should hook at `posts_clauses` for example

```
/**
 * Class Custom_Rest
 * @author 
 */
class Custom_Rest
{
    /**
     * init 
     * Add Rest Hooks
     *
     * @return void
     * @author 
     */
    public static function init()
    {
        add_filter( 'posts_clauses' , 'Custom_Rest::orderby' );
    }


    /**
     * orderby
     * Order posts by menu_order
     *
     * @return void
     * @author 
     */
    public static function orderby($v) {

        if ( $GLOBALS['wp']->query_vars['rest_route'] == '/wp/v2/posts' ) {
            // old value is  "wp_posts.post_date DESC"
            $v['orderby'] = str_replace('post_date', 'menu_order', $v['orderby']);
            return $v;
        }

    }

}


add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'Custom_Rest::init' );
```